# Adding a new JSON key from an existing JSON value

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON;

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2022-06-20",
    "result": 24
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2022-06-21",
    "result": 56
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "start": "2022-06-21",
    "result": 78
  }
]
```

I'm wanting to add 2 new values to each array above using JQ, `dimension` and `date`, but `date` needs to be a copy of the existing key value `start`. The expected output is as below;

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2022-06-20",
    "result": 24,
    "date": "2022-06-20",
    "dimension": "new"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2022-06-21",
    "result": 56,
    "date": "2022-06-21",
    "dimension": "new"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "start": "2022-06-21",
    "result": 78,
    "date": "2022-06-21",
    "dimension": "new"
  }
]
```

The jq I have at present can add the new key `dimension`, but I can't figure out how to copy `start -> date`

```
jq '.[] += {"dimension": "new"}' input.json
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

Just create the new key / value pairs.

```bash
jq 'map(.date = .start | .dimension = "new")' input.json
```

Comment: @Inian, `sh` makes more sense than `none`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have tried the following:

```
.[] += { date: .start, dimension: "new" }    // WRONG
```

But it's not quite right since `.` is the array, not the element of the array. You can use `|=` as a topicalizer.

```
.[] |= ( . += { date: .start, dimension: "new" } )
```

But I'd use `map` instead.

```
map( . += { date: .start, dimension: "new" } )
```

---

Alternatively,

```
. += { date: .start, dimension: "new" }
```

can also also be achieved using

```
.date = .start | .dimension: "new"
```

So you could use

```
.[] |= ( .date = .start | .dimension: "new" )
```

or

```
map( .date = .start | .dimension = "new" )
```